# How backward compatible is Guava/Google Collections?

Tags: java, guava

I am working on large application with multiple projects all still use Google Collections 1.0. I want to upgrade to Guava 12. The test coverage over the projects is not great. Has anyone had similar experience in upgrading this, and is there any incompatibilities? What are the major issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guava contributor here.

Guava 12 is almost entirely backward-compatible with Google Collections, but a very few methods have gone through the mandated 18-month deprecation period and been deleted; see https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=836 .

That said, *nobody* should still be on Google Collections, and we very strongly encourage you to migrate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I finally managed to upgrade Google Collection 1.0 to Guava 13. A few unit tests failed because they used Set and earlier version of the Set maintained insertion order, so I had to refactor them, but all in all, it went flawless.